# Find minimum values in intervals using awk

Tags: shell, awk

I would like to find the minimum of all columns in each 5 row interval.

e.g.
input file

```
2       3       2
2       3       3
8       9       5
5       3       4
7       2       2
0       4       2
5       6       4
6       4       3
3       8       4
2       3       4
```

Desire Output

```
2       2       2
0       3       2
```

My following script is working when select all rows e.g. NR=10, but when I am selecting NR=5, it is not printing the desired output.

```
awk '
{
   for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
      if (i in min) {
         if ($i < min[i]) {
            min[i]=$i;
            count[i]++
         }
      } else {
         min[i]=$i;
         count[i]++
      }}}
      NR%5==0{
      for (i in min) {
      min1=count[i]?min[i]:0;
      printf ("%10.3f ", min1)
   }
   printf ("\n");
 }'
```

I can't understand where is the mistake.

Comment: I use your script and it runs normally and shows the expected results. Does you change the NR to 5 in expression "NR%5==0"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to nullify old variable value and delete previous values of array so that each iteration it starts from null and don't use previous iteration values which will end up in giving false positive values. Tested it in site
https://ideone.com/u0hy15

```
awk '
{
   for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
      if (i in min) {
         if ($i < min[i]) {
            min[i]=$i;
            count[i]++
         }
      } else {
         min[i]=$i;
         count[i]++
      }}}
      NR%5==0{
      for (i in min) {
      min1=count[i]?min[i]:0;
      printf ("%10.3f ", min1)
      }
      printf ("\n");
      min1=""
      delete min
 }' Input_file
```

I added `min1=""` and `delete min` in OP's code attempt as an improvement and fix.

Comment: Yes. I understood it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Kay, your welcome cheers and happy learning on this great site SO.